# Key Error when trying to drop rows in pandas dataframe based on filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am unable to drop dataframe rows due to key error.  I am trying:

df.drop(df['Year_Map'] == 2021], axis=0, inplace=True)

Error: raise KeyError(f"{labels[mask]} not found in axis"

What is the proper way to drop rows with a filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.drop(df[df.Year_Map == '2021'].index, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you.  For this, I receive A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.  I see explanations for this which I don't understand, so I am trying to ensure I go about this the right way.